# ADB offline issue

Tags: android, adb, offline

I made a program to backup files in android devices. To put it simply, it works in background of Windows like a server and when a defined android device (with its LAN IP) connects to home's WiFi network it looks for specific files in specific folders in device and backups them.

My problem is, for some devices (e.g Samsung Note 4), after a few successful WiFi connections (or a few days later) the device starts to appear offline. To fix this, I need to reset the authorities in device or do the reconnection procedure of my program with USB cable again. I researched the web in-depth but couldn't find a way to make offline devices online automatically.

Most of 'ADB offline' solutions on the web works well, but i need to do this automatically over WiFi within my program.

-ADB kill-server & start-server, not working,
-ADB disconnect & connect, not working too.

Comment: I think it's impossible to fix this without usb cable connection as part of the security process :/ (error 10061, to fix i need to do, 'adb tcpip <port number>' while device is connected physicaly.)

Comment: i guess, it is a part of android security.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your antivirus and then try again or add adb.exe as exception in your antivirus.